# Acumatica. How to create parameters based on a given date

Tags: acumatica

I have a report that use a cutoff date, based on this date I have to read records from 3 months ago, is there any way I can create parameters to use base on this date? 
for instance I was considering to create period parameters from given date as 07/13/2018:

begperiod = 05-2018 
endperiod = 07-2018.

Any idea? is there any other way to use this fields on the filters as parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to adjust the date in your Filters on the line sending the date to be compared to SQL. You'd want to put in the Value1 column something like this:

=DateAdd( @Date, 'm', -3)

What that does is it takes your date parameter and subtracts 3 months from it. The entire line should look something like this:

DACTableName.DateFieldName GreaterOrEqual =DateAdd( @StartDate, 'm', -3)

Comment: Thanks Eric, I will try that.